# What's the purpose of InterruptibleChannel interface extends Channel interface in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, extends

I know it sounds like a dumb question.  But since InterruptibleChannel only declare one method:

```
void close()
           throws IOException
```

which is the same name/signature in Channel interface.  What is the purpose of such interface inheritance ?

Is this for reflection purpose in Java runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose is to codify the contract offered by interruptible channels directly into the type system. The guarantees of the contract were deemed important enough to justify that.

Specifically note this sentence in the documentation of [InterruptibleChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/InterruptibleChannel.html):

> A channel supports asynchronous closing and interruption if, and only if, it implements this interface. This can be tested at runtime, if necessary, via the `instanceof` operator.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same signature, but it is stated as also being able to throw `AsynchronousCloseException` (which is also an `IOException`).

In practise, this is effectively a "marker" interface, and whilst functionally equivalent to using `Channel`, using `InterruptibleChannel` may make it's usage clearer to anyone reading the code.